# CSS - Text with Blurr Background

Tags: html, css

I've been trying for quite a while to achieve the effect of having the background of a text block to be blurred, to be able to have more readability on the text on top of the pictures.

But I keep getting both the background and text blurred. Now this has to be inline css since I have to put it in each entry.

This is what I'm trying

```
<div style=  "background:white;  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);  filter:blur(4px);  -o-filter:blur(4px);  -ms-filter:blur(4px);  -moz-filter:blur(4px);  -webkit-filter:blur(4px); z-index: -1; padding: 5px;">
    <p style= "z-index: 1;">
        Desde hace 17 años Tybso se mantiene fiel a la filosofía de crear piezas únicas hechas 100% a mano pensadas siempre como ese objeto  que  es capaz de unir  y resaltar el modo en que la gente come, vive y celebra alrededor de la comida y la buena cocina!
    </p>
</div>
```

This is the [link to see what's happening](http://tybso.com/quienes-somos/).

Comment: Please show some code.  It probably has something to do with which selector you are using in your CSS.

Comment: @SableFoste He has code in there, it just wasn't formatted correctly. I have an edit pending approval...

Comment: Just a side note, try to avoid inline styles like that, especially when posting here on SO. It makes it more difficult for us to read.

Comment: Sry! Imma newby at this thing... Where do I approve the edit?

Comment: Could a <span> tag be used maybe? (I'm just investigating to see the possible options)

Comment: Well I managed to apply those blur filters to the image container in the background... That way i don't need to do any inline styling on the entry on the CMS...

I think this will work perfectly, the image gets blurred but the text remains intact!!!

Thanks guys for the help!!! :D

(how do I close this post or put it as finished?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Dryden Long, you should try to avoid long styles like this.  However, you also have styled the `<div>` whereas I would recommend you style the `<p>`.  Like:

```
<div>
    <h1>This is not blurry</h1>
    <p style= "background:white;  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);  filter:blur(4px);  -o-filter:blur(4px);  -ms-filter:blur(4px);  -moz-filter:blur(4px);  -webkit-filter:blur(4px); z-index: -1; padding: 5px;z-index: 1;">
        Desde hace 17 años Tybso se mantiene fiel a la filosofía de crear piezas únicas hechas 100% a mano pensadas siempre como ese objeto  que  es capaz de unir  y resaltar el modo en que la gente come, vive y celebra alrededor de la comida y la buena cocina!
    </p>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/sablefoste/JaazU/1/

Comment: But I tryed that, but I keep getting the text blurred... The idea is that the text doesn't get blurred, only the background, where the text is, so one can read it better.

Answer (score 0):

Filter operates over a whole div, not just the background.

Try adding this

```
<p style = "filter:-;  -o-filter:-;  -ms-filter:-;  -moz-filter:-;  -webkit-filter:-;">
```

it worked on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JustHannah/7Nm9c/)

Answer (score 0):

modifying sable foste's code to make the example jsfiddle, but all you need to do is have two divs, 1 with a blur background and 1 that is normal, and position the normal one over the blur.

http://jsfiddle.net/pW83w/

```
.blur {background:#e5ffcc;  background:rgba(229,255,204,0.5);  filter:blur(4px);  -o-filter:blur(4px);  -ms-filter:blur(4px);  -moz-filter:blur(4px);  -webkit-filter:blur(4px); z-index: -1; padding: 5px;z-index: 1; height: 5em; width: 20em; position: absolute;}

.noBlur {
    font-weight: bold;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but how do I position then the text over the blurred div?

Comment: give .noBlur a negative top margin in em.... something like margin-top: -5em;  (the number will be however tall .blur is)